# Where can I find a WinForms control that mimics the iTunes stack/fill/progress bar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, controls

I just want a single 100% stack bar control, not the CHARTS that most are offering.
Similar to representing the hard drive space usage of iTunes...

[image]

Basically, I must be able to define how many items, the % value of each item. Specifying the colors would be just luxury feature, by default it should automatically define a different color for every item.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard to create in an afternoon.

Comment: Agreed, with a little bit of geometry math you could have a very nice control in a couple of hours.

Comment: Would you be willing to create it for me then? :D Thanks for your feedback guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your original title sort of threw me off. I don't think I would call this a "stack bar" control. But after looking at the screenshot, I think I know what you mean…

Someone has already written exactly the control you seek for WinForms, and it is available on [here on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17763/iTunes-Bar-Look-a-Like).

It looks very much like the iTunes control, with perhaps a little less overdone gradient effects:

[image]

It's provided as a DLL, so all you have to do to start using it is to add a reference to that DLL to your project. [The license is very permissive](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17763/iTunes-Bar-Look-a-Like?msg=2272344#xx2272344xx), so you can also make any customizations you desire to the control (for instance, adding rounded corners or more drop shadows), and recompile the DLL, or even include the code directly into your project.

Comment: Thanks, Im looking at this and it looks pretty good so far. Will have to create some sort of prototype first. Just asking on the license (I'm not that good with lawyer speak).. I plan to use this in a commercial application, and of course the source codes would not be released. Is this ok?

Comment: Nvm, I just saw in the comments section that I could use it 'any way I like'.

Comment: So after trying it out, I can say that this is not what I had in mind. It does not let me create new 'partitions' for another item. Please refer to this crude image i uploaded. [link](http://i2.lulzimg.com/509e1777de.png)

Comment: Sorry, I can't merge or edit my comments so it's like im spamming, really sorry! So just check the image, I think it's really much more to the 100% stacked bar that I mentioned. I can add items, they take some percentage out of 100% thereby filling the bar.

Comment: Yeah, apparently it doesn't do that. I don't know, it just looked like the image. I remember using it once when I taught myself how to use gradient effects when custom drawing controls. Then after I saw how gaudy it looked, I quickly got over it and used a standard `ProgressBar` control. You'll have to write the code yourself to implement "partitions". This isn't really a "coder for hire" website.

Comment: Yup, my comment at top is just a poke to those guys. And my original intention as you know is to know if there are existing controls. Anyways, thanks for it though, I am currently customizing it.